# Unable to get Swagger ui working with springboot getting white label error (403)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Hello I've been trying to setup swagger to my spring-boot project but I'm getting the white label error when i open the port 8080 in my localhost to open the swagger api

[This is the error I get in my browser when I enter http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jACVb.png)

Swagger dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`SwaggerConfig` class:

```
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final String SWAGGER_API_VERSION = "1.0";
    private static final String LICENSE_TEXT = "License";
    private static final String title = "Inhalo REST API";
    private static final String description = "RESTful API for Inhalo";

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(title)
                .description(description)
                .license(LICENSE_TEXT)
                .version(SWAGGER_API_VERSION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket productsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*"))
                .build();
    }
```

This is my `WebSecurity` class:

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.MEDICINE_ALL, String.valueOf(AUTH_WHITELIST)).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

I tried various options but still getting the same white label error